# How can I read from different Amazon RDS instances using one endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-route53, amazon-aurora, aws-cloudmap

I’m gonna implement the following pattern using RDS Aurora instances:

- I have to import into my DB large amount of data (about 30 millions
  of records) two times a day
- Gonna create 2 instances: A and B
- While data is being imported into the Instance A (it is about 30 minutes), user can read from the Instance B. And after successful data import he/she starts to read from the Instance A.
- As far as I understand, I can use Route53 or CloudMap to map some URL to the specific endpoints of my Instances A and B, and I’m gonna swap instances by Cron.

Is it technically possible to implement such pattern in AWS or should I use some another approach for solving the problem?

Comment: Aurora already provides writer and reader endpoints urls. Do you want to use different ones?

Comment: Hi @Marcin, thanks for your reply.
The conditions of my task are such that I must delete all records (about 30 millions) and after that insert about the same quantity.
At the same time, the user must be able to read from the database. 
So can I somehow use Aurora's out-of-the box tools for solving that?